# RHEL 7.6 - Bootable USB created with kickstart only works on the system it was created on

Tags: redhat, kickstart, usb-boot

[Edit] I got it to work using this thread:

https://access.redhat.com/discussions/1422213

The actual script was simlar to this:

```
 mkdir "/var/tmp/RHEL-7.6 Server.x86_64"
# cd "/run/media/jradtke/RHEL-7.6 Server.x86_64"
# cp -rPf * "/var/tmp/RHEL-7.6 Server.x86_64"
# cd "/var/tmp/RHEL-7.7 Server.x86_64"
# mkisofs -r -T -J -V "RHEL-7.7 Server.x86_64" \
-b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat \
-no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table \
-o  /home/images/rhel-server-7.1-jr-x86_64-dvd.iso .
```

As part of learning kickstart, I created a bootable CD using instructions found here:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/installation_guide/s1-kickstart2-putkickstarthere

The created USB successfully boots into the the system it was created from. 
However, when I try to use the system to boot into another machine (same model and disk setup), I get the following message:

"Reboot and select proper boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot Device_"

What could be the issue? I've checked many times to be sure I'm selecting the correct drive (USB) to boot from on both the original and the second system.

FYI, here is more complete description of the process I followed:

1. mkdir /tmp/workdir
2. mkdr /mnt/iso
3. mount the redhat iso:
   mount /var/run/media/root/PC_Image/system/rhel-server-xxxx /mnt/iso
4. cp -pRf /mnt/iso /tmp/workdir
5. cp /root/anaconda-ks.cfg /tmp/workdir/iso/ks.cfg
6. In /tmp/workdir/iso/isolinux/isolinux.cfg, append after the "quiet" in the section "label check"
   rd.live.check quiet ks=hd:UUID=FE44-B535:ks.cfg
7. Generate the iso: 
   genisoimage -U -r -v -T -J -joliet-long -V "RHEL-7.6" -volset "RHEL-7.6" -A "RHEL-7.6" -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -eltorito-alt-boot -e images/efiboot.img -no-emul-boot -o ../NEWISO.iso .
8. Create the image on USB: 
   dd if=/tmp/workdir/NEWISO.iso of=/dev/sdb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would not use any CentOS 6 documentation for CentOS 7.6.
The kickstart syntax has changed a bunch. Use ksvalidator like this:

```
ksvalidator --version RHEL7 mykicker20190502.cfg
```

The main problem is your use of a UUID. Every disk and every disk partition and every logical volume has an unique UUID. (These are assigned by Linux, not the manufacturer.)

Comment: You should look up reverence in the dictionary.